# WCF - No endpoint listening at http localhost + No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it => external network

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

I have issue with hosing WCF service in console. Tried to search here but could not find solution of this issue even if it is similar to other issues here.

Hosting is very simple.

C# - Host

```
WCFSrv = new WCFService();
WCFSrvHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(WCFService));
udaWCFSrvHost.Open();
```

Config:

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WCF_Service.WCFService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WCF_Service.IWCFService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:23456/WCFService/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="True"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicTimeouts" closeTimeout="00:00:30" openTimeout="00:00:30"
          receiveTimeout="00:00:30" sendTimeout="00:00:30" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

I can reach service through WcfTestClient from localhost and invoke methods offered by service.

I can reach service through WcfTestClient from same network, however cant invoke methods offered by service. Once I try to invoke method I receive error message:

```
There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost:23456/WCFService/ that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.
```

...

```
Inner Exception:
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:23456
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
   at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)
```

I tried to check whether there is port 23456 open and app is listening on that port through netstat -an and port 23456 is open and listening.

When I tried to modify base address (instead of localhost:23456 I put there real IP of server in network e.g. 10.xx.xx.xx) I was able to invoke methods as well but this is just workaround for internal solution.

Server and port should be open to external network and accessbile through internet. I tried to reach service from internet and I am able to reach service from internet (proof that port is open) but facing to same issue => cant invoke methods due to issue written above.

Does anyone have experience with same issue and can help me please?

Comment: it doesn't look like you've updated the client with the real address of your service, and it's still looking at localhost.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply,I think you are close but dont what to do. Because when I am adding reference to simple test client console app. it finds service on remote address. In WcfTestClient I can see config of service...and there is exact address, which I have in host application app.config file -> localhost or internal IP (depends what I put there)...maybe I dont understand which address should be in Host app.config (currently using localhost or local IP from internal network) and whether client application should have also some service configuration in its own app.config?

Comment: In the host I would leave base address out unless you are hosting multiple services from the same host, check the clients app.config as that is where I believe it to be wrong.

Comment: Hi Mike, issue was exactly in client app.config, resp. I thought WcfTestClient will use service address as endpoint address and it seems it use the one, which can read in config file from Host machine. When I used simple client app with target endpoint address, everything works as charm. My bad was that I used WcfTestClient to test it from external network. Problem solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Answered in Comments, put here for completeness.

Check the client config points at your server correctly and not localhost.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to open the host. I too am using a console app.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to WCF, but I've go the same issue latelly. I've just made a config file o the client project, and a wrote there the address of the endpoint:

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WCF_Service.WCFService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WCF_Service.IWCFService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:23456/WCFService/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
```

You can use this reference: http://dotnetmentors.com/how-to-host-wcf-service-in-iis-7.aspx

From my point o view is very in handy. If it not works, try to recreate the project.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, unfortunately I'm not using IIS to host service but just console app with code as written above.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are binding to the wrong IP address try this:

```
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://0.0.0.0:23456/WCFService/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
```

Using 0.0.0.0 instead of localhost will bind your service to all IPs on that host machine.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, I tried what you suggest and got another error message. Now Im not able invoke methods even from localhost. Current error message is: Failed to invoke the service. Possible causes: The service is offline or inaccessible; the client-side configuration does not match the proxy; the existing proxy is invalid. Refer to the stack trace for more detail. You can try to recover by starting a new proxy, restoring to default configuration, or refreshing the service.

Answer (score 0):

**Thanks to all for support.**

**Solution for my issue:**

Dont use WcfTestClient to test service from external network, at least in my case I faced issues described in my question.

For beginners simple advice when you have service hosted out of IIS

1. Use config file to define WCF settings in your project (e.g WCF Service Library)
2. Dont forget to copy setting from your WCF service project to Host application into app.config
3. When test from external network, use simple client app with own app.config, where endpoint has to lead to target service.

M.